# To prove gcd of two polynomials is $1$.

Tags: polynomials, field-theory

Let $f_p(x)=x^p-x^{p-1}-....-x-1$ be a polynomial. Now, we have to prove that--

$(x^p − x,f_p(x)) = 1 \iff f_p(m) \neq 0  \forall m\in \mathbb{F}_p$

I have already proved the forward implication but please help me prove the backward implication.

Thanks!

Comment: In $\Bbb{F}_p[x]$ we have the factorization $$x^p-x=\prod_{m\in\Bbb{F}_p}(x-m),$$ so what is there to prove? In other words, the equivalence holds for **all** polynomials in $\Bbb{F}_p[x]$. Not just $f_p(x)$.

Comment: Sorry, that came out a bit harsh. Anyway, you probably have the tools to prove that factorization: Little Fermat, basic facts about polynomials over a (commutative) field,... Then the conclusion follows. You know the factorization into primes of one argument of the gcd, and can simply test whether any of those primes are factors of the other argument.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen That's ok. I am just a 3rd-year undergraduate student, so all these things are new to me. Actually, I was stuck in a small part of a paper that I am reading. Sometimes easy things don't click you know. Thank you very much for the help.